# Laravel Logging - Monolog stderr ignores logLevel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.7 in a docker container.
My goal is to write error-log directly to stderr instead of laravel.log

logging.php

```
<?php
return [

'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['stderr'], //before it was stderr
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'error',
        ],
//...
        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'level' => 'error',
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
        ],
//...
    ],
];
```

The log target itself is working - laravel.log is empty - but it seems like the log level is ignored. In the docker logs I get also the debug messages

```
docker-compose logs --tail=100 container
...
ESC[36mcontainer_1         |ESC[0m [2019-07-01 09:57:51] local.DEBUG: ...
...
```

If I just change `channels` (`stack`) from `stderr` to `single` the logs (but only error level) are appended correctly to laravel.log

Answer (score 1):

Put the 'level' within 'with' prop, since the with prop will be passed to the [StreamHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/11fb4f92702f98577c95c8ea1e61b937f8f70859/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php#L44) constructor

```
'stderr' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            'level' => 'error',
        ],
    ],
```